# Trying to solve $\sqrt{2\cos^2(x)-\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt2 \sin(x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation is

$$\sqrt{2\cos^2(x)-\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt2 \sin(x)=0$$

I solve it thus:

$$
\begin{cases}
2\cos^2(x)-\sqrt3=2\sin^2(x) \\
-\sqrt2 \sin(x)\ge 0 \iff \sin(x)\le 0
\end{cases}
$$

The first equation boils down to

$$2\cos^2(x)=2(1-\cos^2(x))+\sqrt3$$
$$4cos^2(x)-2=\sqrt3$$
$$2(2\cos^2(x)-1)=\sqrt3$$
$$2\cos(2x)=\sqrt3$$
$$\cos(2x)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$2x=\pm \arccos(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})+2n\pi$$
$$2x=\pm \frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi$$
$$x=\pm \frac{\pi}{12}+n\pi$$

Considering the condition $\sin(x)\le 0$, we are left with

$$x=- \frac{\pi}{12}+n\pi$$

But the textbook's answer is

$$x=- \frac{\pi}{12}+2n\pi; x=- \frac{11\pi}{12}+2n\pi$$

What did I overlook?

---

P.S. The problem and the answer from the texbook:

[image]

Comment: It appears you did everything right up until you look at the condition $\sin(x)\le0$ to reduce your answer-which values of $x$ will satisfy this? For example, If you were to plug in $n=1$ for your solution, then $x=\frac{11\pi}{12}$; however, $\sin(\frac{11\pi}{12})>0$

Comment: @Brent - thank you! So I need to retain the periodicity $2\pi n$, I see. But I still don't understand why where should exist the second $x=-\frac{11\pi}{12}+2\pi n$. It would result in $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ with $n=0$

Comment: Did you also ensure that $2\cos^2(x)-\sqrt{3} \ge 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-\sqrt3$$

$$\iff2\sin^2x=2(1-\sin^2x)-\sqrt3$$

$$\iff\sin^2x=\dfrac{2-\sqrt3}4=\dfrac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{8}$$

As $\sin x<0,\sin x=-\dfrac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi6-\dfrac\pi4\right)$

$x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\dfrac\pi6-\dfrac\pi4\right)$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to look for collections of problems to train myself in exercising transformations like $\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=\sin\left( \dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac\pi4\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

As Brent points out in his comment, your only mistake was applying the condition $\sin x<0$ at the end:

1) If $x=\frac{\pi}{12}+n\pi$, $\;\;\sin x>0$ for $n$ even and $\sin x<0$ for $n$ odd, so this gives

$\hspace{.4 in} x=\frac{\pi}{12}+(2n+1)\pi=\frac{13\pi}{12}+2n\pi=-\frac{11\pi}{12}+2n\pi$

2) If $x=-\frac{\pi}{12}+n\pi$, $\;\;\sin x<0$ for $n$ even and $\sin x>0$ for $n$ odd, so this gives

$\hspace{.4 in} x=-\frac{\pi}{12}+2n\pi=\frac{23\pi}{12}+2n\pi$

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, the author of the guide says in the beginning that applying conditions is one particular stage at which pupils stumble and lose points at exams.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y=2\cos^2y-1$ on

$$2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-\sqrt3$$

$$\iff1-\cos2x=1+\cos2x-\sqrt3\iff\cos2x=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=\cos30^\circ$$

$$2x=360^\circ n\pm30^\circ\iff x=180^\circ n\pm15^\circ$$ where $n$ in any integer

**Case**$\#1:$ $+\implies x=180^\circ n+15^\circ$

But as $\sin x<0,x$ lies in the third or in the fourth quadrant

$\implies n$ must be odd $=2m+1$(say)

**Case**$\#2:$ $-\implies x=180^\circ n-15^\circ$

For the reason mentioned in Case$\#1,$ here $n$ must be even $=2m$(say)

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the fact that $\cos^2{x}=1-\sin^2{x}$. Then solve for $\sin{x}$, then solve for $x$. $\frac{\pi}{12}=15^o$

Comment: But what's wrong with solving the whole thing via $\cos(x)$?

Comment: @CopperKettle \\ In doing so, you would have to extract a square root. I just chose the simpler of the two choices.